# Error in ValidationExpression when using in XSLT

Tags: asp.net, xslt

My XSLT shows that there is error in the below line, but i could not figure it out

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="validatorEmail{@id}" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="{@id}" ErrorMessage="username@domain.com" 

ValidationExpression="^(([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\w-]{2,}))@((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|([a-zA-Z]+[\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$" />
```

Error Message:

```
Expected token '}', found ','.  ...+\.)+[\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\w-]{2 -->,<-- }))@((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|... Forms.xslt
```

What is wrong with this?

Comment: Looks like you need to escape the braces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSLT `{` and `}` are used to inject dynamic values in attribute value templates. You need to double them to escape them in your regular expression:

```
ValidationExpression="^(([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{{1}}|[\w-]{{2,}}))..."
```